# How to account for tabwidget height in layout?

Tags: android

I have a two activities that I switch using tabs. I am having a problem where my activity content does not resize properly to account for the height of the tab widget (therefore the activity content shows clipped behind the tabs). I have the tabs at the bottom. I have tried playing with the tab layout, etc but with no luck.

Is there a way when designing a layout (for the tab content activity) to account for the tab height in android? My guess is that the way I have designed my layout for the activity is too tall after adding it to the tab host. This is possible on iOS but don't know how to do it on android. Any ideas?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution is to use fixed size tabs e.g.

```
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp">
    </TabWidget>
```

Comment: And depending on the screen size (small, normal, large, xlarge) I could have different heights for the tabs. Then when designing the activity layout, I would have a placeholder view with this height. I think this could work, I will pursue this option. Thanks for the quick response!